# Firebase : How To Get key in order after Delete key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy7We.jpg)

How to keep the key sequence after **Delete**? I want it to be 0..1..2..3..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the name of your keys, there is no API for doing that. If you want to change the name of a key you need to copy that particular object to another location, change the name and delete the old one. But to change the name of key is not possible in Firebase.